# The text in a tabular environement goes out of margins

Tags: tables, margins

[image]

I need to write a long paragraph in my table, but the text goes out of the margins..
Here is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}

       \textbf{P1.1} & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\

       \textbf{P4.1} &  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\

\end{tabular}
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Use scalable `p{<width>}` column. `aaa...` and `bbb...` are bad examples for long text, as TeX can't hyphenate them, due to not being actual words.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{blindtext}% \blindtext creates a paragraph of dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{0.6\textwidth}}
       \textbf{P1.1} & \blindtext \cr
       \textbf{P4.1} & \blindtext \cr
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]